# Start tmux session which not closing after running script

Tags: linux, tmux

How can I create an tmux session with script (e.g.)

```
tmux new-session python3 --version
```

If I need the session not to end?

Comment: Why are you running a command that terminates to start a new session?

Comment: A session ends when the last window closes, and a window closes when the command running in it (or rather, in its only pane) exits. It's not clear if you want to run a command that *doesn't* exit immediately (say, an interactive shell), or if you simply want the session to persist with an inactive window.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using the `tmux send-keys` command which sends commands to an existing session from the command-line (or a script):

```
tmux new-session -s test -d                       # Creates a session named 'test' and stays detached.
tmux send-keys -t test "python3 --version" Enter  # Sends the command you wanted to the session.
                                                  # Here, the command was executed and the session is still alive.
tmux attach -t test                               # (Optional) If you want to attach to your session after the command was executed.
```

---

If the commands you want to send are in a script, you can send as a command the execution of this script:

If the script is `python_ver.sh` (make sure the script is executable):

```
#!/bin/sh

python3 --version
```

Then you'd go:

```
tmux new-session -s test -d                       # Creates a session named 'test' and stays detached.
tmux send-keys -t test "./python_ver.sh" Enter    # Sends the command you wanted to the session.
                                                  # Here, the command was executed and the session is still alive.
tmux attach -t test                               # (Optional) If you want to attach to your session after the command was executed.
```